# Average calculation in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, average

I am trying to speed up a python snippet.

Given two equal-sized (numpy) arrays, the goal is to find the average of values in one array, say a, corresponding to the values of another array, say b. The indices of the arrays are in sync.

For example;

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
b = np.array([10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20])
```

There are two distinct values in `a`, 1 and 2. The values in `b` where there is a "1" in `a` at the same index are [10, 10, 10]. Hence average(1) is 10. Analogously, average(2) is 20.

We can assume that the distinct set of values in `a` are known apriori. The values in `a` need not be consecutive, the order is random. I have chosen the example as such just to ease the description.

Here is how I approached it:

```
   # Accumulate the total sum and count
    for index, val in np.ndenumerate(a):
        val_to_sum[val] += b[index]
        val_to_count[val] += 1

    # Calculate the mean
    for val in val_to_sum.keys():
        if val_to_count[val]:  # skip vals with zero count
            val_to_mean[val] = val_to_sum[val] / val_to_count[val]
```

Here `val_to_sum` and `val_to_count` are dictionaries that are initialized to zeros based on the known list of values that can be seen in `a` (1 and 2 in this case).

I doubt that this is the fastest way to calculate it. I expect the lists to be quite long, say a few million, and the set of possible values to be in the orders of tens.

How can I speed up this computation?

**Could the solution be?** 
Inspired by one of the answers below, this might do it:

```
for val in a 
  b[a==val].mean()
```

Comment: See this:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-average-list-python/ and this :https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-find-the-average-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: The link given is a plain average calculation, which is not the case here.

Comment: You can do it by removing the duplicate if it is the case.

Comment: How many distinct values do you expect there to be in `a`?

Comment: "I expect the lists to be quite long, say a few million, and the set of possible values to be in the orders of tens." say ~100 distinct values

Comment: @skadio You can change 'for val in a:' to 'for val in np.unique(a):'.  It will generate a mean for each unique value in a, not once for each element in a. I.e twice through the loop in your example instead of six times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
b = np.array([10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20])

np.average(b[a==1])
np.average(b[a==2])
```

For larger datasets:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(1,30,1000000)
b = np.random.random(size=1000000)

for x in set(a):
  print("Average for values marked {0}: {1}".format(x,np.average(b[a==x])))
```

Comment: b[a] returns 

>> array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])

Not sure what that means. And np.average(b[a]) returns 
>> 10.0

I need two outputs. In this case average(1) = 10 and average(2) = 20

Comment: may be b[a==1].mean() 
b[a==2).mean()

Comment: @skadio: The `a==1` and `a==2` should work. See the revised answer.

Comment: @skadio: This also scales well to larger datasets. I've added a second piece showing this.

Comment: This works well! Thanks.

Any particular advantage between using 

np.average(b[a==x]) vs. b[a==x].mean()

Comment: @skadio: Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You can go over the list once:

```
means_dict = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    val = a[i]
    n = b[i]
    if val not in means_dict.keys():
        means_dict[val] = np.array([0.0,0.0])
    arr = means_dict[val]
    arr[0] = arr[0] * (arr[1] / (arr[1] + 1)) + n * (1 / (arr[1] + 1))
    arr[1] = arr[1] + 1
```

calculating running average for each one of the values. in the end you will have a dict, with each value avarage, and the count.

**Edit:**

Actually, playing around, showed this to be having the best results:

```
def f3(a,b):
    means = {}
    for val in set(a):
      means[val] = np.average(b[a==val]) 
    return means
```

Which is similar to what you suggested, just going over the `set`, saving much time.

Comment: Thank you! can you please elaborate on why np.average() is faster than .mean()?

Comment: Actually it's not, corrected myself, thought so, and some empirical testing showed it was faster, but now when looking into the source seems like I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by removing the duplicate :
So, try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
b = np.array([10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20])

a=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a))
b=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(b))  
print(b)
```

if you have different  elements in b so use this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
b = np.array([10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20])   
d = {}

for l, n in zip(a, b):
    d.setdefault(l, []).append(n)

for key in d:
    print key, sum(d[key])/len(d[key])
```

code:https://onlinegdb.com/BJih3DplE

Comment: I am not sure if the data frame option would be faster than operating with numpy arrays?

Comment: Run the second one.